# setTimeout continously running the function its in?

Tags: javascript, timer

So I have a function which is called from an `onload` event:

```
var called = 0;

function getAll()
{
   var msg = "hello everyone";
   alert("hi");
   setTimeout(startTimerRepeat, 5000, msg);
}

function startTimerRepeat(content)
{
   document.getElementById('howmanyLbl').innerText = "Called " + called + " times, " + msg;
}
```

I expected the `startTimerRepeat()` function to be called every 5 seconds, it does. However it seems the `getAll()` function is also executing every 5 seconds as an alert with "hi" continously appears every 5 seconds.

Does anyone understand what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: `I expected the startTimerRepeat() function to be called every 5 seconds` where are you doing it? who is calling `startTimerRepeat` every 5 seconds?

Comment: Answer to your question in title: nope, `setInterval` do it continously.

Comment: You'd need to add more code to your question for us to figure that out. Specifically where you are calling `getAll()` from. Also, `setTimeout()` only executes a function one time, after a delay. `setInterval()` is what you are looking for here.

Comment: I assume that `startTimerRepeat()` is only being called every 5 seconds because you are calling `getAll()` every 5 seconds somewhere else, as `setTimeout()` only executes the function once, after the specified delay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> However it seems the getAll() function is also executing every 5
>   seconds as an alert with "hi" continously appears every 5 seconds.

If you don't want `hi` to be alerted everytime, but still innerText to be updated every 5 seconds, then change your methods to

```
var called = 0;
function getAll()
{
   var msg = "hello everyone";
   alert("hi");
   setTimeout(function(){
      startTimerRepeat(msg );
   }, 5000, msg);
}

function startTimerRepeat(msg)
{
   document.getElementById('howmanyLbl').innerText = "Called " + (called++) + " times, " + msg;
   setTimeout(function(){
      startTimerRepeat(msg );
   }, 5000, msg);
}
```

Comment: This can't answer the question as OP hasn't provided all the code which is causing the error - ie the code that is causing the `getAll` to be called every 5 seconds